# What does "to be off with someone" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, british-english

What does "to be off with someone" mean in this sentence "Ever since I said no to him, he's been very off with me."?

Comment: It's a bit weird but it implies that he became unfriendly..??

Comment: Perfectly normal in the UK. She's been a bit off with me for a couple of weeks. I found out it's because I made a joke about Brexit supporters being stupid, and her favourite uncle is Nigel Farage.

Comment: Although the answers given here are correct, I just thought it worth mentioning that the phrase "Be off with you!" means either "get going" or "are you serious?" depending on context - another use of the same construction that shouldn't be confused.

Comment: Someone from the UK wrote the sentence. My impression is that it's not commonly used in the US?

Comment: Well I didn't really find an exact meaning of the word "off" that would fit the description well, but it is more like saying 'he was being rather aloof after the incident last week'. Meaning his behaviour towards me has changed, somewhat slightly or more depending on how intense the incident was, and how much it affected him.

Comment: In the UK, this would suggest somebody is acting abnormal towards them - normally due to something that has happened, e.g. Ever since I stole his lunch money, he'd been acting a bit "off" - Different from "getting off" which suggests getting pleasure from something.

Comment: How about "I'm off" = "I'm leaving"; "I'm off with my colleague" = "My colleague and I are both leaving together"?

Comment: @Eclairyang Yes, rarely used like that in the U.S.

Comment: To the British speakers: Does "to be off with someone" function as a idiom in British English? I know: to act off, yes. But not to be off. Be off is only for things.

Comment: From my perspective in the US, I don't know if it's idiomatic but it's a perfectly understandable usage (merely, "different").  @Stef that's a great point, that other usage is how I initially interpreted the question when I read the title.

Comment: @Lambie - Perfectly normal, as I thought my comment above made clear. "A week later, she was off with me all night. 'Look, what's wrong?' I asked. She turned to me with cold, brown eyes. 'I'm not pregnant,' she said." - "I honestly don't get Izzie, she was off with me this morning, maybe she's intimidated by me" - "Speaking of his rival, Lewis F, he said: 'He was off with me.' 'Everyone else greeted me properly,' "

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks so much. Very clear now. I appreciate your explanation. :) I will delete my comment. Sometimes, these little phrasal things are different.

Comment: Bummer. I thought she's off with him on a camping trip in the backcountry and I'll be grandfather soon!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [**off**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/off)
> *adjective*
> 33. slightly abnormal
> 34. not up to standard; not so good or satisfactory as usual; inferior or subnormal

It's between these two definitions. If I say, "He's been *off* with me," or, "He's been very *off* with me," it means that things are not the same between us, that he hasn't been treating me like he normally does, that there's an awkwardness, issue, or something going on with him that's affecting his behavior towards me, like maybe he's upset with me about something I said or did, which I maybe don't even know what that something is because I didn't realize he took offense, got hurt feelings, or had whatever emotional reaction he had that's making things *off* between us as he maybe hasn't told me, or maybe he's just been in a funk or in a funny mood lately about something completely unrelated to me, but whatever it is up with him, the way he's been with me, the way our relationship has been lately, has been not like it usually is, and not in a good way. It's that strangeness in him and how it's affecting how he's treating me by his treatment of me being substandard that I'm commenting on.

Being that the usage is somewhat slangy or informal, I believe this definition from *Urban Dictionary* sums it up, as well:

> 4
> [**off**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=off)
> To be weird, off center, not normal.
> "she's a bit off"

Comment: Your Urban Dictionary usage is "short for" [***off the wall***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-the-wall) - perhaps with a nod to BrE ***off one's trolley*** and Australian ***off the planet*** (bonkers, insane). It doesn't have any particular implication of "unfriendly", which I'm sure is central to OP's context.

Comment: That's an unfounded assumption. It doesn't say that. I've never taken it to mean that, either. "Off the wall" is straight-up bizarre, extremely unconventional (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/off-the-wall), and as your source states, often intentional. When someone's "off," it tends to be subtle, the person saying it saying it often because others maybe haven't noticed it but only they themselves notice that that person is being *off* with them. Anyway, that's neither here nor there. Unless you have some foundation for your assertion that it's "short for 'off the wall,'" it's unfounded.

Comment: Well, in my own answer, I've advised *learners* to avoid the usage anyway, *because the intended meaning won't always be understood*. And our two comments above simply underline the relevance of that advice! :)

Comment: You have no foundation for that assertion, either. My comments don't underline the relevance of any such advice, much less provide foundation, quite to the contrary. This is a widely used and extremely common expression. To find an abundance of examples of just how widely and how often this expression is used, I've done a Google Ngram and added the word "seemed," which is often couched beforehand, in order to differentiate this particular usage of "off" from others, like that might mean a person is off in any other respect, like "off of work."

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+seemed+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20seemed%20off%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20seemed%20off%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: Ho hum. It seems plain as day to me that if someone's attitude is described as "off" *after* having been refused something, the intended meaning is far more likely to be my *cool in manner, unfriendly*, rather than your *weird* or @randomhead's *inappropriate*. But what do I know?

Comment: Now you're unfoundedly interpreting "weird" as meaning something other than its usage in the citation for the definition of "off," which is made clear in its further elaboration, and you're glossing over the fact that your answer asserts "off" is contracted from "offhand," which again, is an assertion you make without foundation, unlike all of my assertions. If I'm being "off" with you, I'm acting unlike I normally do in some way with you that has you feeling like things are not as they should be, which is not in any way necessarily my being brusque, curt, cavalier, etc., what "offhand" means.

Answer (score 7):

> [**off**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off#English), adjective
> 7. Inappropriate; untoward
> *I felt that his comments were a bit **off**.*

As used in your example, the meaning is not quite as above, but similar. It sounds like the person is being unfriendly, distant, and awkward, rather than inappropriate.

Answer (score 7):

As a native speaker, one aspect I'd often understood of phrases like "a bit off" was  by analogy to something like milk or cheese (or indeed other perishable items like meat) that has turned sour or otherwise started to acquire an unpleasant flavour or odour, which could also be described as "a bit off".

Conversely, when it has curdled and become so sour nobody would have any doubts it had "gone off", it would be considered "very off".

By analogy, when someone is interacting with you in a different (and less pleasant) way than you would normally expect, you could describe that interaction as "a bit off" or even "very off" depending on the circumstances - not the interaction you were expecting, and either subtly or very noticeably different to the normal friendly response you expected.

In essence, it is suggesting that the relationship/friendship/interaction has at least started to turn sour.

Comment: It's certainly a commentary on the relationship status. I take it to mean that the relationship has gone _sour_, much like how milk that has spoiled can be said to be "off".  When a relationship is "on", then interactions are smooth and amicable.  When a relationship is "off", then then there is tension or unpleasantness.  But it could also mean specifically _annoyed_ or _irritated_ as in "put off", or informally, "ticked off", or "p***ed off"

Answer (score 1):

I think the cited usage is contracted from [*He's been very **offhand** with me lately*...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very%20off%20with%20me%2Cvery%20off-hand%20with%20me%2Cvery%20offhand%20with%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20offhand%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

> [**offhand**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/offhand)  - *Ungraciously or offensively nonchalant or cool in manner.*

I'd say the contracted version is slightly "slangy". Also it's probably best avoided by non-native speakers (in favour of ***offhand***) because in certain contexts the intended meaning might not be clear (since ***off*** has an awful lot of different meanings! :)

Comment: In the usage I’m used to (as a BrE speaker), *offhand* is completely different from this usage of *off*.  If a co-worker is a bit *offhand* with me, it means they’re being a bit (too?) casual and careless about things, just as the definition you give suggests.  If they’re a bit *off* with me, it means almost the opposite — distant, standoffish, overly reserved.

Comment: Yes, that's the "nonchalant" nuance of the cited definition. I probably overstated the idea of "contracted from" in my answer, but at least ***offhand*** only really spans a 1-dimensional range from "careless" to "unfriendly". The number of possible meanings for ***off*** involves far more than even *three* "clines", so us 3-dimensional human beings can't even properly *visualise* the "semantic range" of the shorter term.

Answer (score 1):

After a clarification in comments, I see that other answers fit the intent of the question.  Just for completeness, note that “He’s off with Joe” (as in the original question) can also mean that he and Joe have gone somewhere together.